# running npm run build throws Error: Can't resolve 'Vue'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

When running npm run build  or nom run dev. the following error is produced.

```html
ERROR in ./src/components/screens/login/login.js?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/eslint-loader??ref--0!./src/components/screens/login/login.js?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Vue' in '/home/builder/build/release/projects/appschoolware/9.9.5/build/src/components/screens/login'
 @ ./src/components/screens/login/login.js?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/eslint-loader??ref--0!./src/components/screens/login/login.js?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 22:0-22 391:45-48
```

dont really understand, the reason for this..hope anyone can help.
My package.json is long so bear with me.

```html
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "test": "npm run unit",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=1024 build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "rrule": "^2.6.8",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.3",
    "@riophae/vue-treeselect": "^0.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "expr-eval": "^1.2.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "flat": "^5.0.2",
    "gradle": "^1.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "qrcode.vue": "^1.7.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-autosuggest": "^2.0.4",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-ctk-date-time-picker": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.4",
    "vue-print-nb": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-qrcode-reader": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-radial-menu": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vue-select": "^2.6.4",
    "vue-swatches": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vue-touch": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vue2-filters": "^0.11.0",
    "vue2-touch-events": "^2.1.0",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-function-name": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^4.1.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.4",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^5.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.7.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "inject-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.5",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.4.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "ora": "^3.4.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.25",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
    "semver": "^5.7.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
    "sinon": "^7.5.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.4.0",
    "transfer-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.4",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^2.3.4",
    "vue-loader": "^15.8.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-emit-all-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.13.0 <13.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 6.12.0"
```

As you see in the file login.js  there is a single line "import Vue from 'Vue' " and thats i think throwing the error..but in my localhost i dont see any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import Vue from 'vue'  was the solution...Capital letters matter!!! careful!